# Search popup box using lightbox

Tags: javascript, popup, modal-dialog

I want to make a popup using lightbox or something like that.

In the popup there will be a search box.

I tired to use different script put I'm to new with javascript to get it working. When I hit the link, it just opens a new page in state of a popupbox.

I want to make something like this:
http://www.jcsl.nl/medewerkers/producten.png

So when I search for a product and when I select it it would appear in the list.

I have this so far, but maybe the script is to old and I should look for something else. I really would like to learn, so if you have better ideas please point me into the right direction:

javascript:

```
var modal = (function () {
    // Generate the HTML and add it to the document
    $modal = $('<div id="modal"></div>');
    $content = $('<div id="content"></div>');
    $close = $('<a id="close" href="#"></a>');

    $modal.hide();
    $modal.append($content, $close);

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('body').append($modal);
    });

    $close.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $modal.hide();
        $content.empty();
    });
    // Open the modal
    return function (content) {
        $content.html(content);
        // Center the modal in the viewport
        $modal.css({
            top: ($(window).height() - $modal.outerHeight()) / 2,
            left: ($(window).width() - $modal.outerWidth()) / 2
        });
        $modal.show();
    };
}());

// Wait until the DOM has loaded before querying the document
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a#popup').click(function (e) {
        modal("<p>This is popup's content.</p>");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

css:

```
#modal {
    position:absolute;
    background:gray;
    padding:8px;
}
#content {
    background:white;
    padding:20px;
}
#close {
    position:absolute;
    background:url(close.png);
    width:24px;
    height:27px;
    top:-7px;
    right:-7px;
}
```

html:

```
<a id="popup" href="includes/search.php">Simple popup</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/ypJRK/

Comment: It seems to be working. See the fiddle I added above. What's the question?

Comment: I use excact the same on my website, but there it isn't working, it just opens another page when I click the link.
Don't I need the next line? I used it, but you removed it from my post?
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I placed the css and java in my <head></head> Is that the right way?

Comment: Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: That's correct, depending on how you did it. Java =/= JavaScript.

Comment: Yes I made a mistake in the right order. This line has to placed first.
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
I hope this answers helps anyone in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake I made was an easy one.

I made a mistake in placing the lines in the right order.

This line has to placed first. So before the .css and javascript file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I hope this answers helps anyone in the future